# One class classification of images using Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, classification

The goal is classifying dog and non-dog. The train dataset only contains dog images. Neural network will be trained using this train dataset only and then tested using test dataset that contains dog and non-dog images.

I followed the [encoder Datacamp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/autoencoder-classifier-python) and in my case, the autoencoder classified all test images as dog which is wrong.

Building CNN for one class classification is not possible too. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Then you have to classify dog vs. no-dog. So you have to classes. One class has images with dogs on them, the other class are images with no dogs. So actually completly random images.

Comment: @TheodorPeifer Yes, you are right. The training process only can utilize the train dataset that contains images of dog only.

Answer (score -1):

The correct term for what you're asking about is *binary classification*.

And you can safely use a CNN for binary classification. The question is just how you model the output layer. You can either use a softmax layer with two output units (argmax(output) is class 1: dog, class 2: not dog) or use the more traditional method of using a single sigmoid unit as the output (output>0.5: dog, <0.5: no dog). As the softmax normalization is a multiclass extension of sigmoid activation, a sigmoid layer makes more sense on a theoretical basis but if you have trouble implementing this, a softmax should work just as well.

Of course, you'll have to adapt your data labels to fit either approach.

Edit: You need both images of dogs and those that include no dogs. The network needs to know the distributions for both. Just think about your use case and what kind of images you expect that are not dogs. Then collect images that are not dogs and label them accordingly.

Comment: The CNN will be trained with dog images only, is this possible? Any examples on how to do so? Especially on the single sigmoid.

Comment: @jwen You need both dog and not-dog images, generally this should be 50-50 but it can be skewed as this really depends on a lot of specifics in the dataset. For starters, you can collect images that users are likely to encounter that are not dogs and label them as "not dogs". There's no way around this, unfortunately. Getting a balanced dataset is a big topic which we can't cover here and I would recommend you to read up more on that.

Comment: The question asks for a one class CNN not binary.

Comment: @raygozag The question asks for dog vs non-dog which is binary. So having "one class" means doing binary classification. Binary meaning "two" as in 1 and 0. 1 Being the class ("dog") and 0 being the absence of the class ("not dog").

Comment: There are so many things that are not a dog so you cannot possibly give all the examples for non-dog, but it should be possible to  just learn what a dog is and everything else is not a dog.

Comment: @raygozag Ok, so where is the disagreement? I think you're misunderstanding my answer as we're both just describing binary classification. Or you can quote which exact sentence that I wrote you have an issue with? (or write your own answer)

Comment: The problem with your answer is that a binary classifier requires positive and negative examples,  but the number of negative examples is infinite so it's not possible.  You should be able to give positive examples only and anything that doesn't match is a negative instance.  That's why calling it a binary classifier does not apply here. It's more of an unary classifier.

Comment: Theoretically it may be a binary classifier, but practically you can't build such a classifier because of the infinite number of things that are not dogs.

Comment: @raygozag I understand what you're saying but you're simply wrong, binary classification tests for class positive vs negative and not two classes. By your logic terms like "true positive" wouldn't exist for binary classifiers if they didn't have a positive (class present) and a negative (class absent) condition. But they do:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers More examples here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/ryanholbrook/binary-classification Yes, a negative medical test doesn't tell you what your disease is, only what it is NOT. But that's still a binary classifier.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that a binary classifier requires positive and negative examples, but the number of negative examples is infinite so it's not possible. You should be able to give positive examples only and anything that doesn't match is a negative instance. That's why calling it a binary classifier does not apply here. It's more of an unary classifier.